# ListView within HorizontalScrollView and the HorizontalScrollView within ScrollView

Tags: android, listview

this is my layout.xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/h_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nest_list_view_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

there are 2 listviews. 
The first listview is `list_view`; 
The second listview is dynamically added in the LinearLayout(`nest_list_view_container`).

The first ListView will work properly with the `setOnTouchListener` method,
but the second ListView can't be scroll with the same method, only respond to the click event.

Comment: Have you checked this link : https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/scrollview-inside-scrollview-scrolling-problem/

Comment: @MavyaSoni Yes, but it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use recyclerview instead of listview and use this code in it to move recyclerview smoothly :

```
          android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

also I prefer to use :

```
       <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/activity_Recipe_detail_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
              <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="vertical">
                   // ..
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

in this situation

Comment: thanks.  your suggest is very useful. but  android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

it is definitely possible to add listview or recyclerview inside scrollview 
as I used it in my project many times .
an example :

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/activity_Recipe_detail_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/activity_Recipe_detail_content_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_Recipe_detail_hashtag_card"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/recipe_detail_card_margin_top"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/recipe_detail_card_margin_top"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/radius_recipe_detail_card"
                        app:cardElevation="1dp"
                        app:contentPadding="16dp">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/activity_Recipe_detail_hashtag_list"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            tools:listitem="@layout/hashtag" />
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should Never keep ListView inside the ScrollView.ListView is itself Scrollable upon the list being updated dynamically.Remove any ViewGroup above ListView and try again.

Comment: it is ok if using nestedScrollView @ujjwal